# Making post request with Symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony, postman

I have a function in Symfony3 that posts data to a mysql database.  The function looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/LegoPieces")
 * @METHOD("POST")
 * @View()
 *
 * @Annotations\QueryParam(
 * name="piece", nullable=false, description="piece"
 * )
 * @Annotations\QueryParam(
 * name="type", nullable=false, description="type"
 * )
 * @Annotations\QueryParam(
 * name="startDate", nullable=false, description="Start Date YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (Should be in the future)"
 * )
 * @Annotations\QueryParam(
 * name="endDate", nullable=false, description="End Date YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (Should be no more than 3 weeks in the future)"
 * )
 */
public function postAction(ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
{
    $piece = $paramFetcher->get('piece');
    $type = $paramFetcher->get('type');
    $start = $paramFetcher->get('startDate');
    $end   = $paramFetcher->get('endDate');
    $startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);
    $endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat(' Y-m-d H:i:s', $end);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default');
    $data = new LegoPieces();
    $data->setPiece($piece);
    $data->setType($type);
    $data->setStartDate($startDate);
    $data->setEndDate($endDate);
    $em->persist($data);
    $em->flush();

    return new JsonResponse("LegoPieces Added Successfully", 200);
}
```

When I replace the variables ($piece, $type, $startDate, $endDate) with strings the post request works.  But when I try to make a post request through something like Postman or javascript like this:

```
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/LegoPieces", {
    method: "POST",
    body: {
      startDate: this.startDate,
      endDate: this.endDate,
      piece: this.piece,
      type: this.type
    }
  }).then(response => response.json())
);
});
```

I get a 500 error!  I don't understand- thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you check symfony profiler results ?

Answer (score 2):

Look in your logs what is your error.

But you have to improve your controller ! You don't use Symfony Form and you don't have any validations. Even if your haven't 500 error now, you will have some in the future if you don't respect your entity types.

I also don't understand why you use a post request and don't pass all your parameters in your body. You only use get parameters in the url.

Comment: I originally had the post request in javascript with the body used to pass in parameters (I've edited the post) but it doesn't show anything.  The error says 'Call to a member function format() on boolean' - its showing this I think because its not getting the date parameter!

Comment: @Nespony yes you should use the Form component to manage the hydration of your entities and validate them :)
With that you don't have to worry about your get parameters, date format and creation. After validation you can assume (with the good asserts) that your entity can be persisted to db

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing  what  exception makes  that 500 - you know nothing :(

Try to see  response body

Without  that info - i have only one  idea .

If you arw working  on dev envionment , then  youur  js  request simply may not see  routes (and the other stuff)

clear all contents  of  cache folder

`rm -rf var/cache/*`

and

`php bin/console c:w -e prod`